# store and use lua scripts in redis

Tags: lua, redis

I'm literally 5 minutes into discovering scripting in redis and lua so forgive me if I'm missing some important points but is there any reason not to **save** some **lua functions** in **redis** for reusing as some kind of **module** loading? rough example:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set keyCount "return function(...) return table.getn(redis.call('keys', arg[1])) end"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return loadstring(redis.call('get', KEYS[1]))()(ARGV[1])" 1 keyCount *
```

Comment: just noticed this [tutorial](http://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/) while writing my question

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but it's not really useful. You should probably use [EVALSHA](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha) instead.

Comment: is the script cache specific to a database or is it shared? the [doc](http://redis.io/commands/script-flush) on this is fierce patchy

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's stopping you from doing just what you described, namely storing the Lua script sources in Redis keys.

On the same topic, here's a little idea I had along these lines: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/e030fad40c5583b11e01

EDIT: just to make sure we're on the same page, while there's nothing stopping you, you also probably shouldn't... This wouldn't play well with the cluster's sharding.

Comment: `loadstring` is working just fine here. I'm running `2.6.16` though

Comment: @Reno - hmmm, you're right... I remembered there was a problem w/ it. Oh well :) Edited.

Comment: Our redis runs on a single node so it's not a pb for us. How does this impact a redis cluster though? I'm curious

Comment: In the cluster, each key is assigned to a hash slot. A script's keys cannot span multiple hash slots.